# How can i change the pattern image parameter inside SVG by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

i have to change logo inside embedded SVG, logo image link defined in Pattern and applied to Rect/Path container. Is there a way to change link to image (xlink:href="link_to_logo.svg") by JS?

```
<pattern id="logo" 
    patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
    x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <image x="0" y="0"
        xlink:href="link_to_logo.svg" 
        width="331" height="331">
    </image>
</pattern>

<path id="logo-container" d="M1152 99h331v331h-331z" fill="url(#logo)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#logo img').attr('xlink:href', 'newValue')
```

should do it.

Comment: Can you explain the usage of `img` instead of `image`? When checked the browser changes the DOM from image to img, but I didn't find any creditable source for that change.

Comment: @Dekel sorry that was a typo

Comment: Actually, this wasn't a typo. You current code will **not** work. It will work only with `img`. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, and you @Dekel – it's begin working сonsidering your comment )

Comment: I'll upvote your answer once you give the explanation regarding the `image` vs. `img` :)

Comment: Did you find any reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","href",newValue)
```

in plain js use setAttributeNS.

Comment: Thank you Holger, will try your approach too